# Running war on tomcat7 vs grails run-app

Tags: grails, war, run-app

I am having a problem running grails generated war file on tomcat7. If/when I run the same app with grails run-app all is good and in the proper working order. The exception I get while running tomcat7 and deployed war:

```
2014-08-20 09:17:28,933 [http-bio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ClassNotFoundException occurred when processing request: [GET] /
jline.console.history.History. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jline.console.history.History
    at org.codehaus.plugin.swagger.builder.SwaggerDocsBuilder.buildApiDeclarations(SwaggerDocsBuilder.groovy:71)
    at org.codehaus.plugin.swagger.builder.SwaggerDocsBuilder.rebuild(SwaggerDocsBuilder.groovy:48)
    at org.codehaus.plugin.swagger.builder.SwaggerDocsBuilder.build(SwaggerDocsBuilder.groovy:36)
    at org.codehaus.grails.plugins.swaggerapidocs.SwaggerApiDocsController.resources(SwaggerApiDocsController.groovy:21)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

Line 71 of `SwaggerDocsBuilder.groovy`

```
rules = new BuildPathMap().build(grailsApp)
```

and `BuildPathMap` extends

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.reporting.AnsiConsoleUrlMappingsRenderer
class BuildPathMap extends AnsiConsoleUrlMappingsRenderer {
```

my guess is `AnsiConsoleUrlMappingsRenderer` somehow depends on `jline.console.history.History` but then why is it missing from the war file? Is there something that can be done during the war generation to ensure that ll dependencies are properly packaged?

Comment: Hey @ash can you please validate if my answer is correct ?

Answer (score 3):

Its a bug in grails.

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8532

could fix this with a workaround adding the following snippet to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    copy(todir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib", flatten: "true") {
        fileset(dir: "${grailsHome}/lib", includes: "**/jline-*.jar, **/jansi-*.jar")
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. The JIRA link doesn't though.

Comment: Yeah the JIRA is not working, they migrated it. I stopped using Grails anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I was able to get around this problem by explicitly adding a jLine dependency in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
runtime 'jline:jline:2.12'
```

I did not see this error with Grails 2.5.1, but did with Grails 2.5.4.  Seems like a bug.

Comment: Same here, only appeared when upgrading from 2.5.1 to 2.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Tomcat configured to run an unpacked or packed war.  Development runs as an unpacked war so commands like servlet.getRealPath() return a valid value when running that on a packed war the Tomcat servlet container returns null. In the server.xml search for unpackWARs attribute.

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false">
```

Also some dependencies are added for you when running in development and you need to specify them in the BuildConfig.groovy otherwise they may not be available in the war.

Comment: <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

Comment: "Also some dependencies are added for you when running in development and you need to specify them in the BuildConfig.groovy otherwise they may not be available in the war." - this is something that I find odd but it sure seems like it is the case. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, so in my development I can prevent problems that might occur in production?